# C# select data into the viewmodel using linq

Tags: c#, linq, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel

```
    public class CompanyDetailVM {
      public string CompanyName { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
   }
```

I want to retrieve all the data coming from XML, I cant figure out how to get list of comments too (Comments model consist of CommentText, DateTaken). My code looks like:

```
   var model= new CompanyDetailVM
   {
       CompanyName = detail.Element("result").Element("name").Value,
       Comments = new Models.Comments {  
                CommentText=  detail.Element("result").Element("comment").Element("text"),
                DateTaken = detail.Element("result").Element("comment").Element("date")
       }
   }
```

Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Models.Comments' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

I also dont think doing new Models.Comments is the right way.  How do I fix the code correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you assigned a `Models.Comment` object to a property expecting `IEnumerable<Comments>` type, which then trigger that conversion error. You can create `IEnumerable<Comments>` from XML using LINQ like so :

```
var model= new CompanyDetailVM
{
   CompanyName = detail.Element("result").Element("name").Value,
   Comments = from comment in detail.Element("result").Elements("comment")
              select new Models.Comments 
                     {
                        CommentText = (string)comment.Element("text"),
                        DateTaken = (DateTime)comment.Element("date")
                     }
}
```

Notice that I use `Elements("comment")` (with plural `Elements`) assuming that you may have multiple `<comment>` elements in the XML source.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a single Comment in your XML - as it looks like you do here - then the easiest is to do:

```
var model= new CompanyDetailVM
{
    CompanyName = detail.Element("result").Element("name").Value,
    Comments = new [] { 
        new Models.Comments {  
            CommentText=  detail.Element("result").Element("comment").Element("text"),
            DateTaken = detail.Element("result").Element("comment").Element("date")
        }
    }
 }
```

(Note the shorthand array literal syntax - `new [] { ... }` for easily creating an array (which of course implements `IEnumerable<>`))

If your XML may contain multiple comments, e.g.

```
<result>
    <name>Test</name>
    <comment><text>One</text>...</comment>
    <comment><text>Two</text>...</comment>
</result>
```

Then you might want to move towards using [LinqToXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to transform all `<comment>` tags into `Models.Comments` objects.